# How do I enable automatic page break in mPDF in PHP?

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using `mPDF` to write some dynamic text in my pdf. This is my code:

```
<?php
    function setpageNo($page){
        $page+=1;
        $mpdf->SetFooter("Page: ".$page);
    }
    foreach($arr as $x){
        mpdf.WriteHTML('<div style="text-align:center;">'.$x.'</div>');
    }
?>
```

The thing is the text `$x` is of dynamic length, i.e., it can be as big as a paragraph or as small as one line. So is there a way to enable automatic page breaking and call `setPageNo()` function as soon as the text reaches the footer?

Comment: From [document](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-breaks.html), and from my usage from long time ago, mPDF auto page break if text is too long. From your code, you use `foreach()` loop array. If the result is something that is not auto break word like _aaaaaa_ and you don't use CSS to force break word, it will be to long and auto page break also not working. Try to split word with white space or use CSS to force break it.

Comment: I didn't get it. What are you trying to say?